# Auto OTP verification android xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, one-time-password

I am working on an Android App using Xamarin, in which server sends an OTP and the user needs to enter this OTP in the App, to SignUp for my App. What I want is, that my App should be able to automatically read the OTP sent by the server and to be filled in edit text field of OTP.

I'm almost done to read the message but unable to set the otp in edit text field.

SMS broadcast receiver class:

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
 [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
 public class SMSBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
 {
     private const string IntentAction =   "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
 public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
       try
     {
          if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;
          var bundle = intent.Extras;
         if (bundle == null) return;
         var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus");
          // var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray(pdus.Handle);
          var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray<Java.Lang.Object>(pdus.Handle);
           var msgs = new SmsMessage[castedPdus.Length];
          var sb = new StringBuilder();
         string sender = null;
          for (var i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
              {
              var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[i].Handle)];
                JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[i].Handle, bytes);
              string format = bundle.GetString("format");
             msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu(bytes,format);
             if (sender == null)
                   sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress,System.Environment.NewLine, msgs[i].MessageBody));
                Toast.MakeText(context, sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
           }
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
      {
             Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
     }
     }
 }
```

Here is my main activity:

```
 [Activity(Label = "UserSms", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
 {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
       SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
     SMSBroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new SMSBroadcastReceiver();
     TextView msg = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextOtp);
     Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
        RegisterReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
  }
  }
```

How can I achieve this? Any help or guidance in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Update

```
    public void onSMSReceived(string msgs)
    {
        EditText OtpNumber = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editTextOtp);
        try
        {
            OtpNumber.SetText(msgs.ToString(),null);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are on the finishing line. You only need to do these thing:

1. Create an interface which will have public method `onSMSReceived(String smsMsg)`
2. Instantiate that interface.
3. Implement that interface in `MainActivity` activity.
4. Override `onSMSReceived(String smsMsg)` in your MainActivity
5. Notify MainActivity using above created interface from your SMS Broadcast Receiver.
6. Populate message received in `onSMSReceived(String smsMsg)` in your MainActivity.
7. You are done.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't worked for me.Can you elaborate it little bit.Thanks

Comment: which part you did not understand?

Comment: implemented as you suggested but it didn't worked.Can you provide sample code.It will save my day

Comment: @MohammedDastagir, can you please share code that you have implemented so far?

Comment: Did you created interface like this 

`Public Interface IOTPReceived
 Function onOTPReceived(ByVal otp As String) As String
End Interface`

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting you as I'm new to C#.Please have a look on my Update

Comment: I think you have not created an interface and implemented that to your class. Please read some article related to how create and consume interface in c#.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly how you're doing it, but i did in two ways,
1.User has to enter it manually,
2.We have to read automatically through the programming,
But i faced one problem in reading sms automatically, like sending sms and reading sms are calling at the same time may be like register click event, I found one more way to detect automatically like sending otps two times and storing generated otps in a list of string and comparing with  message.body
Here the problem is we have to send otp two times, still i'm figuring out how to call reading sms part after sometime,,,!

If you want that solution plz mail me at sailokeshgoud@gmail.com